# Как правильно распарсить строку

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как из строки `owner/:ownerUUID/pets/:petUUID` вытащить имена параметров `ownerUUID` и `petUUID` ?

```
makeRequestURL(url, params) {
  console.log("makeRequestURL", url.match(/:(.*)/g));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var url="owner/:ownerUUID/pets/:petUUID";

console.log(url.match(/\/:[^\/]+/g).map(function(val) {
  return val.substr(2);
}));
```

Тут регулярка начинает выделение с подстроки `/:` и далее пока не встретит слэш (`[^\/]+`), а в map() идет удаление не нужных символов (`/:`).